# Minecraft flickers sometimes and colors get buggy on an Intel HD Graphics 3000

Tags: intel-graphics

I really like Ubuntu, but I always had to switch back to Windows just because I couldn't get my Intel HD Graphics 3000 to work. So, 11.10 came out and I'm trying to get things work in this update, so I can finally stay with Ubuntu and use it. Anyways, things seem to be more stable here, but they're still a bit fishy.

I'm doing tests with Minecraft. Currently, there's only 1 minor bug. The game flickers from time to time and the colors get buggy or something

[image]

I read that maybe I should update to kernel 3.1? Maybe 32-bit Ubuntu is better?

It was impossible to play Minecraft in 11.04, but 11.10 is so much more stable.

Answer (score 1):

I run minecraft on archlinux with the same IGP and have the same graphical glitches.

Since arch has a newer kernel, I think it is safe to say, a newer kernel will not help. Switching to Oracle jre does not help either. I suspect a bug in the intel graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

you may not need to update your kernel but by all means it may help i suspect it is because you may be using openJDK, minecraft has problems running under openJDK which is installed on oneiric(11.10) by default you can install oracle's JRE/JDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-7u2-download-1377135.html) you may need to uninstall openJDK before-hand

you may also want to try using the script found on minecraft's download page if you cannot boot it after installing oracle's java

Answer (score 0):

Check out which java you currently using by typing on terminal `java -version` if it says that you are using OpenJDK I would recommend install Oracle java by following steps on: 
[How can I install Sun/Oracle Java 7 JRE](https://askubuntu.com/a/56119/63777).

If it won't help you can try upgrade your video drivers by using [x-swat PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/125197/63777). However it risky that whole system could mess up.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running 64-bit version of Ubuntu, try installing the 32-bit lib files as follows from Terminal:

1. Launch Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Then type the following command $ `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

You may have to reboot for the changes to take affect.